# Mysql Join and Union

Tags: mysql

I have 4 schemas

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(model, speed, ram, hd, price)
Laptop(model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(model, color, type, price)
```

And need to find the model number and price of all products made by a certain manufacturer. If can get just the price and model of all the different products using

```
(select model, price
from Laptop)
union
(select model, price
from PC)
union
(select model, price
from Printer)
```

But cannot figure out how to combine this with my Product schema to get only the certain maker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery would probably be more efficient than multiple joins:

```
select model, price 
from (
    select model, price
    from Laptop
    union
    select model, price
    from PC
    union
    select model, price
    from Printer
) t join product p on t.model = p.model
where p.maker = 'B'
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitly looks better than my version.

Comment: @daemor -- no problem, just make sure you alias the columns -- `select t.model, t.price`...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
select Product.model, Laptop.price
from Product, Laptop
where Product.maker = 'B' and Product.model = Laptop.model
union
select Product.model, Printer.price
from Product, Printer
where Product.maker = 'B' and Product.model = Printer.model
union
select Product.model, PC.price
from Product, PC
where Product.maker = 'B' and Product.model = PC.model;
```